# Como guardar datos en archivos csv con peso definido en python

Tags: python, base-de-datos, csv, io

Se plantea el siguiente caso:

Dado un query a base de datos que me regresa una cantidad `N` de filas donde `N` es un numero muy grande. Quiero guardar esas filas en un archivo csv pero con la siguiente regla:

Cada archivo debe tener un peso igual o menor que P. Donde P es definido por el usuario

Ejemplo:

Digamos que un query a base de datos me retorna 1000 filas y el usario decide guardar en sus datos en archivos csv de maximo 1Kb

Entonces, como logro iterativamente escribir en archivos hasta que su peso sea de 1Kb

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado para lograr esto? Te invito a compartir tu código a modo de [mcve] y a leer [ask]. También realiza el [tour] para poder ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc hasta ahora no he intentado nada porque no encuentro como encarar el problema, he estado buscando pero no consigo informacion que pueda ayudarme con eso

Comment: El único problema que veo es que hasta que no escribes el csv no sabes cuánto va a ocupar en disco. Puedes intentar lo siguiente: itera sobre las filas del dataframe escribiendo un csv acumulativo y comprobando que el tamaño se mantenga por debajo del establecido. Si cumple esa condición copias el csv como "parcial final" y pasas al siguiente parcial.

Comment: Itera sobre cada fila de la query.  En cada iteración, crea una cadena con la línea que iría al csv, (separa los campos por punto y coma o lo que necesites, y con un "\n" final). Calcula cuántos bytes ocupará esa línea en el fichero mediante `len(linea.encode("latin-1"))` por ejemplo (depende de qué encoding necesites en tu csv). Suma ese tamaño a un acumulador y si no excede 1000, vuelca la línea a fichero. Si excede 1000, cierra el fichero, abre uno nuevo, vuelca la línea y reinicia el acumulador con el tamaño de la línea.

Comment: @abulafia Muchas gracias creo que tu solucion sera la que me ayude. Lo implementare y si funciona posteare como respuesta la soluciom. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, fueron de bastante utilidad y me sirvieron para llegar a una respuesta, espero que pueda ayudar a otros.

```
rows = self.cnxn.cursor().execute(sql).fetchall()
    downloaded_rows = 0
    pbar = tqdm(
        self._generator(),
        leave=False,
        desc=f"{downloaded_rows} Downloaded bytes in {file_count} files",
    )
    for _ in pbar:
        for row in rows:
            row = list(map(lambda x: str(x), row))
            current_file_size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
            row_size = sys.getsizeof(",".join(row) + " \n") - sys.getsizeof("")
            downloaded_rows += row_size
            pbar.set_description(
                f"{downloaded_rows} Downloaded bytes in {file_count} files"
            )
            if (current_file_size + row_size) > file_size:
                f.close()
                file_count += 1
                composed_filename = f"{filename}-{str(file_count).zfill(4)}.csv"
                filepath = f"{folder_name}/{composed_filename}"
                csv_writer, f = self._new_writer(filepath, header)

            csv_writer.writerow(row)
            f.flush()
```